# What do these Unicode characters (codepoints) mean in this regex?

Tags: regex, unicode, diacritics, codepoint

I have the following regular expression :
I figured out most of the part which is as follows :

```
ValidationExpression="^[\u0020\u0027\u002C\u002D\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u005F\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00FF°./]{1,256}$"

u0020 : SPACE
u0027 : APOSTROPHE
u002C : COMMA
u002D : HYPHEN / MINUS
u0030-\u0039\ : 0-9
u0041-\u005A : A - Z
u005F : UNDERSCORE
u0061-\u007A\ : a - z

u00C0-\u00FF°./ : ??
```

Need help in understanding the final part of the validation expression :

```
u00C0-\u00FF°./
```

Anyone has any idea what does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

weird... according to the character map on Windows I'd say "À to ÿ"

Those are some variations (accents, cedillas) on A, C, E, I, D, N, O, U, Y, the german Sharp s, ...

Answer (score 2):

\u00C0 - \u00FF are letters with accents on them, though that isn't all of them.  And "°" is just the degree character.  However, "./" should probably be "\." to permit period characters.

Comment: . inside [ ] does not need escaping. Only characters inside [ ] that need escaping is ] and \

Comment: Oh, and the delimiter on those platforms that use them, such as perl and php.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I'm not a regex expert so the small stuff like that does trip me up.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mistitled, you want help with [Unicode](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) [codepoints](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). You can check them, for instance, [here](http://namidst.com/stuff/unidata/).

They are the second half of Latin1 Supplement, including accentuated vocals and some other characters. See the above links.

Comment: The current title is my doing.  Maybe you could tweak it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your result of splitting the original string looks weird, as if you hadn't understood what a Unicode escape sequence is. It should rather look like:

```
\u0020
\u0027
\u002C
\u002D
\u0030-\u0039
\u0041-\u005A
\u005F
\u0061-\u007A
\u00C0-\u00FF
°
.
/
```

You can look up the meaning of these code points at the Unicode web site:

- https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf (Basic Latin)
- https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf (Latin-1 Supplement)
- https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf (Emoticons)

The last three characters mean exactly what is written:

- degree sign
- dot/period/full stop
- forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Using http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/conversion.php
I got:  ',-0-9A-Z_a-zÀ-ÿ

Answer (score -3):

It looks to be the range of characters presented in the last 2 columns in TABLE ASCII-II at the following link to [The Extended ASCII Chart](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm)

Comment: That chart is actually one of *many* extended ASCII's, known as codepage 437.  But we're dealing with Unicode here, not ASCII. For the first 256 codepoints, Unicode happens to be identical to ISO-8859-1, another "extended ASCII" that's very different from cp437.